# Use idapython to print register or memory value when the debugger is running

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

I want to record the value of a certain register or specific memory location when the program is being debugged.
e.g. in the following segment:

```
.text:0FD6268D                 shr     ecx, 4
.text:0FD62690                 and     esi, 0Fh
.text:0FD62693                 movzx   ecx, ds:byte_FF27790[ecx]
.text:0FD6269A                 mov     [edx], cl
.text:0FD6269C                 inc     dword ptr [eax]
.text:0FD6269E                 mov     edx, [eax]
```

This is a part of a function which is accessed many times and I want to print, to file, the values of:

ecx @.text:0FD6268D and ds:byte_FF27790 @.text:0FD62693.
I need this printed every time the program gets there during the debugging.

How can I accomplish this using idapython?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create two Python-functions (menu *File-Script command...*). First for printing EAX and second - for printing memory @FF27790

[image: Python-fuctions]

```
def view_ecx():
    print GetRegValue("ecx")

def view_memory():
    print Byte(0xFF27790)
```

2. Set breakpoints:

   - `@.text:0FD6268D` - set condition `view_ecx()` and choose Python-type
   - `@.text:0FD62693` - set condition `view_memory()` and choose Python-type

Comment: Here is an updated example snippet: `print("msg_id: ", idc.get_reg_value("ecx"))`. It can go straight to breakpoint condition box and will write to Output window.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, 
I cam up with adding this the the BP:

```
def view_mem_0xF3E7790():   
    opAddr = 0xF3E7790
    for byte in idc.get_bytes(opAddr, 16):
        hexChar = ord(byte)
        print chr(hexChar),
print "\n"
```

2 questions:
 1. how can i append the result to a log rather than printing to the screen.
 2. Can i add these BP problematically somehow?, similar to idc.AddBpt(ea)

?

Comment: 2. As I understand, you want something like this:
```idaapi.add_bpt(0xF3E7790, 4, BPT_DEFAULT);
bpt = idaapi.bpt_t();
idaapi.get_bpt(0xF3E7790,bpt);
bpt.elang = 'Python';
bpt.condition = 'view_mem_0xF3E7790()';
idaapi.update_bpt(bpt);
```

Comment: 1. Do you meen write log to file?

Comment: yes, write log to file
thank you

Comment: Then just like in pure Python - https://pythonspot.com/write-file/